# Does piano recycling count as instrument maintenance or is on topic at all?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I recently (something like 1 or 2 years ago) bought an used digital piano off of a comrade who didn't use it anymore.

The instrument is perfectly playable, fit for training, and doesn't show much sign of being that much used, so I intend to keep it for a while since it's in working condition. But I expect that I would eventually buy a new one in the (far) future.

Is it on topic to ask what to do with an used old model digital piano? I tried looking around for information about "piano recycling" or "piano trading" or anything, but I couldn't find much for now.

Comment: Personally, I feel that this would entirely "on-topic". Some musicians tend to accumulate instruments in which they have no longer have interest. Finding out what others have done in order to unburden themselves of unwanted instruments would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I don't think this would be on topic - it's very opinion-based. Answers could range from disassembling it for components (which I tend to do) to giving it away or selling it. There really isn't a market for recycling these - if they work, find someone who can use it. If it doesn't, take it to wherever your local electronics recycling plant is - but none of this is about musical practice or performance.